# Find all numbers in specified intervals [Min; Max] and write them in one column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with a specific excel task. Although I searched the web thoroughly for tips and parts of code I could use, I was not able to get near a functioning solution.

This is my problem:

I have around 30 Worksheets with two columns each.
The number of Rows varies from WS to WS but the two columns on each sheet are equally long.
The first column of each Sheet contains minimum values and the second column holds the respective maximum values.
E.g.

```
  |   A  |  B
1 | 1000 | 1010  
2 | 2020 | 2025
```

Now I need one single column with all values from these intervals including the Max and Min values.

Preferred solution in Column C:
1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025

I thought of highlighting the two columns and then activating a macro to generate the list. I would then repeat this process for each WS manually. Some sheets have only 4 to 20 rows but some have over 7000 rows.
And if it helps anything: The numbers are postcodes ;-)

I'd be very grateful for any kind of help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want just one long string?

Comment: Check out the [Range.DataSeries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839262.aspx) or [Range.AutoFill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) method. With a loop over the first/second column this should be all you need

Comment: @ Dirkl Reichel: Well, not necessarily. I'd prefer any solution. I can also modify the data or layout if needed. In the end I just need one column per ws containing all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long, ColIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim min As Long, max As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ColIndex = 1
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            min = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
            max = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            For j = min To max
                ws.Cells(ColIndex, 3).Value = j
                ColIndex = ColIndex + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly the solution I needed! Thanks

Comment: @Sipsmith - Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution you can use as you like would be kinda like this:

```
Public Function getZIPs(rng As Range) As String
  Dim myVal As Variant, str As String, i As Long, j As Long
  myVal = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value

  For i = 1 To UBound(myVal)
    If IsNumeric(myVal(i, 1)) And IsNumeric(myVal(i, 2)) And Len(myVal(i, 1)) > 0 And Len(myVal(i, 2)) > 0 Then
      If myVal(i, 1) <= myVal(i, 2) Then

        For j = myVal(i, 1) To myVal(i, 2)
          str = str & ", " & j
        Next

      End If
    End If
  Next

  getZIPs = Mid(str, 3)
End Function
```

Put this into a module and then either go for C1: `=getZIPs(A1:B1)` and auto fill down or directly `=getZIPs(A:B)` to get all numbers in one cell or use it in a sub to do it automatically.

If you have any questions, just ask :)

**EDIT**:

If you want it all exactly in the one-column-way, you can use this (should be fast):

```
Sub getMyList()

  Dim sCell As Range, gCell As Range
  Set gCell = ActiveSheet.[A1:B1]
  Set sCell = ActiveSheet.[C1]

  Dim sList As Variant

  While IsNumeric(gCell(1)) And IsNumeric(gCell(2)) And Len(gCell(1)) > 0 And Len(gCell(2)) > 0

    If gCell(1) = gCell(2) Then
      sCell.Value = gCell(1)
      Set sCell = sCell.Offset(1)
    Else
      sList = Evaluate("ROW(" & gCell(1) & ":" & gCell(2) & ")")
      sCell.Resize(UBound(sList)).Value = sList
      Set sCell = sCell.Offset(UBound(sList))
    End If

      Set gCell = gCell.Offset(1)

  Wend

End Sub
```

If you have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! The function works but it writes multiple values in one cell, separated by comma. What I actually need is a a solution where each value gets copied in in cell in one column. So basically I get a really long column. I think this can only be achieved by a sub.

Comment: @Sipsmith added another solution to fit your *"I'd prefer any solution."*-question ;)

Answer (score 0):

**edited**: to have one big string in column "C" (added two lines in each code)

**edited 2**: added "zip3" solution for having all values listed in "C" column only

you could use either following ways

```
Option Explicit
Sub zips3()
   'list values in column "C" in sequence from all min to max in columns "A" and "B" 
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim cell As Range

   For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       For Each cell In sht.Range("A1:A" & sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
           With cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 2).Resize(, cell.Offset(, 1).Value - cell.Value + 1)
               .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC1+COLUMN()-4"
               sht.Range("C" & sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1).Resize(.Columns.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Value)
               .ClearContents
           End With
       Next cell
       If IsEmpty(sht.Range("C1")) Then sht.Range("C1").Delete (xlShiftUp)
   Next sht
End Sub


Sub zips()
   'list values in column "C" from corresponding min to max in columns "A" and "B"
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim j As Long

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each cell In sht.Range("A1:A" & sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            For j = cell.Value To cell.Offset(, 1).Value
                cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1) = j
            Next j
            'lines added to have one bg string in column "C"
            cell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = "'" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(cell.Offset(, 2), cell.Offset(, 2).End(xlToRight)))), ",")
            Range(cell.Offset(, 3), cell.Offset(, 3).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents
        Next cell
    Next sht
End Sub

Sub zips2()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each cell In sht.Range("A1:A" & sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Resize(, cell.Offset(, 1).Value - cell.Value + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC1+COLUMN()-3"
            'lines added to have one bg string in column "C"
            cell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = "'" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(cell.Offset(, 2), cell.Offset(, 2).End(xlToRight)))), ",")
            Range(cell.Offset(, 3), cell.Offset(, 3).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents
        Next cell
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunatelly I couldn't get this to work properly. This code does not result in one column with all values but writes all values in the respective row.

Comment: it was tested: what problems did you have? (which error thrown and at what line)

Comment: well I saw your answer to Dirkl Reichel question so I went for _any_ solution. But it can be easily adapted to fill one column only. I'll post an edit for that

Comment: Ah sorry, I had some formatting issues. No problem on your side. Sorry if I didn't specify what I needed in the initial question. All the values have to go in one single column ...even of it's going to be a lot of rows :)

Comment: I think I see now what you meant for _"All the values have to go in one single column"_: they must be listed in single-value cells in column "C". see edited code